# Typescript error doesn't go away after file corrected

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, angular6

I created in VS2017, using the  ASP.Net Core template and Angular a project. It all works.

It was using Angular 5, so I updated to Angular 6 and Rxjs 6 and then copied over a working Angular 6, Rxjs 6 app to this project.

When I try to run it I get Cannot Get / and that is because there are a few errors.

One error in particular is :

> Error  TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module '../../services/authentication.service'.

So I changed the `import` statement to:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
```

which is the correct location, saved the file and did the build again and the error is THE SAME. It's like the compiler is looking at the old file instead of the corrected file.

What can be causing this? I am running the file by `Debug > Start without debugging` or `Cntrl-F5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's like the compiler is looking at the old file instead of the corrected file.

Not the compiler, the IDE. Just restart the IDE and it will be fine.

Comment: Is that a common problem? Restarting the IDE after every change seems a bit dramatic or is there something else going on?

Comment: Setting up watchers for file systems is *troublesome*. Only need restarts for critical stuff like moving files OR changing git branches etc.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually got most of the problems worked out and now it's working fine.